# Python converting from tuple to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I know for many of you that would be easy thing to do, but for me no. So I'm trying to output data from shell, but I'm stucked when I have to transform it into string. I tried with `for`, but didn't work. So basically, what I'm trying is: for each new line in my shell, output new line. I'll give an example - the `free -m` command. Its output is

```
  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:           144        512        111          0          0        121
  -/+ buffers/cache:         23        232
  Swap:            0          0          0
```

So, what I wrote so far is:

```
import commands
foo...
sout = commands.getstatusoutput(inp)
    return ' '.join(str(line) for line in sout)
foo...
```

But the output is only one line (the first line - total, used, free, shared etc)

and I want new line for each new line like the output in the shell. If I leave it without .join it outputs something like

```
(0, '             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached\nMem:           512        144        368          0          0        121\n-/+ buffers/cache:         21        234\nSwap:            0          0          0')
```

and since I want it to be a string, I even tried `'\n'.join`, but it outputed only `0` (wtf). Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't care about the command status, you may try commands.getoutput instead of commands.getstatusoutput. It returns string.


Sample code:
type(commands.getoutput('ls))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use os.popen which is much more convenient.

```
print os.popen('free -m').read()
```

You might want to read this thread to acquire a good overview of the options available to run shell commands from within python [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, I did it with `readlines()` then `for line in sout:` `print line`. Thanks again, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The entire string is in the tuple, with line breaks and everything, so I suppose all you need to do is:

```
print sout[1]
```

Assuming that `sout` is the tuple you show in your question:

```
(0, '             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached\nMem:           512        144        368          0          0        121\n-/+ buffers/cache:         21        234\nSwap:            0          0          0')
```

Comment: @maikati: My question is assuming that `sout` contains the tuple in your question. If that is not the case, replace `sout` with which ever variable contains that tuple.

Answer (score 0):

just make a check for newline character and then insert a new line character in your output. here actually you getting input as a whole. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can get the same result:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    // Create a subprocess and then interact with the process by reading data from 
    // stdout, untill the end-of-file is reached. Since communicate return tuple 
    // in the form of stdout, stderr), Capture only the output.

    (result, errcode) = Popen('free -m', stdout = PIPE, shell = True).communicate()
    print result
```